# pdf2svg may be what I am looking for,I need to scan/convert architects drawings (25 years old) to svg accurately

Tags: svg

I have no programming ability am a long time user of win7 and since recently ubuntu/zorin
I need to scan/convert our architects house drawings to svg to input to FreeCAD
I am hoping to extend the house and need appropriate qaulity drawings
I have already tried some other converters but the svg quality was abismal
brian E

Comment: Ask here instead: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape has a tracing feature which provides what you describe. It has been used in the FreeCAD community before, but I'm not sure how usable the output will be for architectural drawings. Have a look at https://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html